# how to click in a link inside a list inside another list

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

i cant make the driver click on link text called "sell"
i already have tried many possibilities, included this:

```
List <WebElement> eventLogList = driver.findElements(By.className("nav navbar-nav"));
```

here's the HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown open">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">event log<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/scan/receive"><span class="text">income</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/scan/delivery"><span class="text">outcome</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Consult<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/report/trackable"><span class="text" id="trackable_report">buy</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/report/event"><span class="text" id="event">details</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">serie number<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="/generate-ium"><span class="text" id="generate-ium">sell</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="/generate-ium"><span class="text" id="generate-ium">resell</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
```

Comment: try finding it by xpath: `"//ul//a/span[@text='sell']"` and in your description you may point to the exact element, took me a while until I found it. PS: it's wrong to have 2 ids with the same name!

Answer (score 2):

you can try using cssselector as follows:

```
 List <WebElement> eventLogList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelctor(".nav.navbar-nav"));
```

and then to click Sell use:

```
 eventLogList.get(0).findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(3) ul>li>a")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

`By.className` does not allow using multiple classes, just a single one as a name.

What you want is `By.cssSelector`:

```
List <WebElement> eventLogList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".nav .navbar-nav"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly try to click on the link using

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("sell").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. This is dropdown which on hover/click opens a menu. Before clicking on menu items you need to ensure that the dropdown is expanded and the menu items are visible at until they are clicked. When the dropdown menu is visible, `aria-expanded` will be set to `true`.

Here is how I handled it:

```
public boolean selectFromDropdown(String parentMenuText, String childMenuText) {
    boolean flag = false;
    // Get the nav bar
    WebElement navBar = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".nav.navbar-nav"));

    // Get all parent menu items
    List<WebElement> allNavItems = navBar.findElements(By.xpath(".//li[contains(@class,'dropdown')]"));

    // Loop through allNavItems to find the parentMenuText
    for(WebElement parentMenuItem : allNavItems) {
        WebElement parentMenuLink = parentMenuItem.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'" + parentMenuItem + "')]"));
        String actualText = parentMenuLink.getText();
        if(actualText.equalsIgnoreCase(parentMenuText) {
            // if true, found parent menu item
            parentMenuLink.click();
            // When parentMenuLink is clicked, it will trigger a DOM update in the aria-expanded attributes and therefore we need to re-initialize the element to avoid StaleElementException
            parentMenuLink = parentMenuItem.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(text(),'" + parentMenuItem + "')]"));
            if(parentMenuLink.getAttribute("aria-expanded").equals("true")) {
                //Get the child UL
                WebElement childMenuContainer = parentMenuItem.findElement(By.xpath(".//ul[@role='menu']"));

                // Get the child menu link
                WebElement childMenuLink = childMenuContainer.findElements(By.xpath(".//li/a/span[@class='text' and contains(text(),'" + childMenuText + "')]/.."));
                // Click on the child menu link
                childMenuLink.click();
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if(flag) {
            break; // Break out of the loop if child menu link has been clicked
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!
i've already tried this solution on the beggining of the development, by some reason it was not working.
After some attempts the solution below solved my problem
code following:

```
        WebElement btnConsult= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='bs-example-navbar-collapse-1']/ul[1]/li[2]/a"));
    btnConsult.click();

    WebElement btnDetails = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Details"));
    btnDetails.click();
```